# What does "da" mean in "tabeta bakari da"?

Tags: grammar, particles, copula, particle-ばかり

I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) that *da* is a short casual form of *desu*. But what does it mean in this phrase? or why it is used?

> *Tabeta bakari da.*

Comment: It doesn't mean anything else. Here, too, `"da" is a short casual form of desu`. What exactly is your question?

Comment: tabeta is to eat , bakari is "just" or something, so what meaning adds "da" to the sentence? is a verbal tense or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. [食]{た}べたばかりだ。(Tabeta bakari da)
>    I have just eaten.
> 2. 食べたばかりなの？(Tabeta bakari nano?)
>    Have you just eaten?
> 3. 食べたばかりではない。(Tabeta bakari dewa nai)
>    I have not just eaten.

There is a writing style named 論文調 that is for an essay in Japanese,
and the end of sentence is 'da/dearu' meaning the assertion.
It seems that any examples of the language textbooks use this style usually.
That is a mechanical style at the opposite end of the polite style of expressions such a honorific language,
and it is a kind of literary style.

Comment: Does "it means 1" mean 「食べたばかり means 食べたばかりだ」?

Comment: Where did you get 食べたばかり (without だ) from? It's not in the question. I don't quite understand how this answers the question "why do we need *da* in *bakari da*?".

Comment: I think that だ is required because it is a predicate.
However, in the case of ばかり＋だ, it is often omitted in spoken language.
Whenever the word at the end of a sentence is not a predicate, I almost think that is abbreviated.
There is a style called 体言止め as an exception tho. そう思った私。

Comment: @nariuji I think you should add what you said in your comment to your answer, since it's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 12):

ばかり【bakari】 is a 副助詞 (adverbial particle), which is derived from the 連用形 (-masu stem) of the verb はかる. But the particle (and 連用形 in general) behaves much like a noun. (Join to other noun-like words with の, make into a predicate by adding だ, etc.)

Now you essentially have a noun phrase 食べたばかり. To make a sentence out of this, you have to add だ・です (or だった・でした in the past tense).

This is the same as in

> 本だ。
>   *hon da.*
>   [This] is [a] book.

Comment: Your answer raised me another question actually. Why taberu behaves like a noun? is there a list of noun-like verbs and words in japanese? or is it how is used in this sentence what makes it noun like?

Comment: @Pablo *Taberu* doesn't behave like a noun.  I think you may have misunderstood the answer.

Comment: @Pablo *taberu* is a verb, did you mean to ask about *bakari*? *bakari* does behave like a noun. This is true for many *-masu* stems of verbs. Sometimes the *-masu* stem would be best thought of as a particular conjugation of a verb (still "flexible"), but sometimes the *-masu* stem has "hardened" into a noun, e.g. 受付 = 受け付け (= *-masu* stem of the verb 受け付ける). There shouldn't be a "list of exceptions"; as far as I can tell it is a general feature of Japanese. (I don't have any examples where the *-masu* stem of *taberu*, which would be *tabe*, behaves like a noun, though.)

Comment: ^ I can only think of 三角食べ 

Comment: I missunderstoond you before, I thought you were saying both of them (the particle and the verb) behave like a noun, thanks!

Comment: 終止形の「だ」はカタコトに聞こえるからあまり使わない方が良いよ

Comment: @nariuji そうですか。「食べたばかり**だ**よ」とよく聞くと思いますが。

Comment: 「よ」は終助詞ですね。原形のままの言葉は日常であまり使わないんじゃないかなあ。

Comment: @nariuji 「『食べたばかり』のほうが『食べたばかりだ』よりも自然なのか」というのは、もともとの質問「なぜ『食べたばかりだ』で『だ』を使うか・使えるか」とはまた別だと思います。

Comment: 文末が副助詞で終わる言葉は暗黙の省略があるので(「スープを飲んだだけ(のところです)」「いつも食べてばかり(います)」)、
これを助動詞「だ」で終わるのは、活用の元となる原形を付けるため述語だと理解しています。
もし活用がないなら私は必須では無いと思います。文法書等はこれを必須と書いているのでしょうかね。

Comment: 付けるための述語* Sorry for my typo.

Comment: 「さっき～～したばっかり**だ** /です。」「今さっき帰ったばかり**だ** /です 。」「さっき帰らはったばっかり**や** 。(だ→や in Kansai dialect)」「～～してばっか(り) **や** 。」などはカタコトには聞こえませんし、普通に使えると思います。くだけた日常会話では、「だ」を省いたり代わりに「よ」を使ったりもしますが、きちんとした書き言葉などでは「～ばかりだ。」「～したばかりです。」「～したばかりである。」などにしますし、文法的には正しいです。

Comment: 「スープを飲んだだけのところです」はどういう意味ですか。

Comment: 「あとは～ばかり」「いつも～ばかり」「まだ～ばかり」はそれぞれ"食べる・食べて・食べた"が入りますが、
これが必ず｢だ｣を付けることになっているかどうかだろうか。
例えば「なぜなら～だから」は助動詞なし。なぜなら「だ」が既に助動詞だから。
だが、助詞の種類が少し違うとはいえ、それらの違いはこじつけにしか見えないな。

Comment: 私の内容は、丁寧語や語調を整える語尾も含めて、ただの原形「だ」で終わる言い方は通常多くはない、と言ったもので、それが元々の論点だと思います。
「です」でも「だよ」でもそれは原形のみとは違います。質問にも「です」については先に書かれていました。
私も、なぜ「だ」を除いてはいけないのか疑問です。

Answer (score 3):

As you said, “だ” is a colloquial form of “です,” a predicate meaning “is, am,” and "食べたばかりだ” means “I’ve finished meal just now.”

“だ” here functions as I am in the state of having finished meal just now.